# Derive 445 Quarter for any given date

Tags: sql, oracle

I need assistance writing a query that determines the quarter of a given date based on 445 FY calendar. The FY ends on first Friday of February every year.

For example in attached image the table has the order id and order created date. Based on the order created date I want to determine which 445 FY quarter it falls in.

[image: Mock Table]

Comment: Pleas enclose data, tables and code into your question rather than linking images.

Comment: We are not a code writing service. please provide your tries and code and we will try to help you

Answer (score 0):

Use a case statement with a between condition to divide up your custom quarters. You will need to enter the start and end dates of each quarter:

```
Select
 Case 
   when date between 'startdateQ1' and 'enddateQ1' then 'Quarter1'
   when date between 'startdateQ2' and 'enddateQ2' then 'Quarter2'
   when date between 'startdateQ3' and 'enddateQ3' then 'Quarter3'
   when date between 'startdateQ4' and 'enddateQ4' then 'Quarter4'
   when date is null then 'Null'
   else 'Unknown'
   end
 As Current_Quarter
From DB
```